# after decimal allow 4 digit and before decimal 2 using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

i have one script to check insertvalue in textbox.

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
<script>
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

this script work good to allow only number.
but i want script to check this type of condition.
0.123456
11.12345

**total 7 digit in textbox

after decimal 4 if before decimal 2 digit

if before decimal 1 then 5 digit after decimal**.

how its work any script or anything else which helpful me.
thanks

Comment: 7 digits or 7 characters? A `.` is not a digit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with the following `regex`:

`^(\d\.\d{5}|\d{2}\.\d{4})$`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/nW5qI7

Comment: I am not to familiar with regex.  I would like to allow up to (4).(4).  Would that be  ^(\d\.\d{5}|\d{4}\.\d{4})$  ?   What does the 5 mean in this statement? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [autoNumeric.js](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) for my decimal operations and it's just great.

You can check the site for more info but for what you want, you need to use (of course after adding library and calling `init`)

```
data-v-max="99.9999" data-m-dec="5"
```

in input properties.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ergtB/)**

Comment: OP wants to allow exactly 6 significant digits. Your solution allows `12.34567`, which is not what was wanted ;)

Comment: @Batu Zet if we have 1 digit before decimal then after decimal allow 5 total with decimal textbox allow 7 charcter

Answer (score 1):

UI tip: *never* stop the user from typing what they want.

When the user has finished typing (ie. `onblur`, `onchange`, whatever you want), *then* check if the input matches your format and notify them seamlessly if not.

HTML5 does this magically for you.

```
 <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]\.[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}" />
```

Note use of `text` rather than `number` - using `number` with a specific format of decimal numbers is too tricky to be worth it.

Comment: @MohitPandey - Re: your attempted edit, HTML `pattern` implies `^$` anchoring.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var num = $('#number').val();
    if(num && !isNaN(num * 1)) {
        if(num.replace(/\./, '').length != 7) {
            return false;
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using HTML5 and don't know regex

```
var num = $('#number').val();
var nString = String(num);
var nArray = nString.split('.');

if((nArray[0].length == 1 && nArray[1].length == 6) || (nArray[0].length == 2 && nArray[1].length == 5))
{
      //do something
}
else
      return false;
```